# Maven custom archetype: boilerplate date and time stamps (and other meta info)?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to learn how to create custom Maven archetypes. I have the following directory structure.

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── resources
            ├── archetype-resources
            │   ├── pom.xml
            │   └── src
            │       └── main
            │           └── java
            │               └── Sketch.java
            └── META-INF
                └── maven
                    └── archetype-metadata.xml
```

`Sketch.java` is the main source template file and in it, I want to create the following boilerplate:

```
package $package;

/**
 * Author: $author
 * Created: ${maven.build.timestamp}
 * Java version: ${maven.compiler.source} 
 * Processing version: core-${processing.core.version}
 * Description: $description
 */

import processing.core.PApplet;

... // (rest of template code)
```

Just like the `$package` variable is a stand-in for whatever package structure the user chooses (group id), I want to substitute the timestamp of creation, author name, etc through properties `$author`, `${maven.build.timestamp}` and so on...

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</project.timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <processing.core.version>3.3.6</processing.core.version>
  </properties>
```

I am a little confused about where exactly I should define these, ie. *in which POM file*? **There are two**: one for the archetype (in root `.`) and one which gets generated when a project is created in Maven with this archetype (in `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml`).